# Wordpress setup: wp-config and content transfer

Tags: wordpress

Can I delete the wp-config-sample.php after I save it as wp-config.php?

Also, is there a way I can transfer all my content from my old web pages which are not in a database to Wordpress, instead of manually adding all the content page by page? Keep in mind that I'm adding Wordpress to my GoDaddy hosting account.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can delete the sample configuration file if you want to.

You could theoretically write a script to take the content from your pages and insert them into Wordpress, but depending on the number of pages and the diversity of the structure/content of the pages it may be more worthwhile to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete the file. There is no harm in it as the file name says its just a sample file.

Well copying the content from your old web pages is a tiring job. And as Ghills said its not an easy task to write a script to move the content as there are lot of other jobs involved when you write a post. Example : Categories, Tags, images etc.

Also you cannot trust the script completely as you will be moving a HTML content and dont know how wordpress editor will accept it.

Its better to o it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can delete the file, because it is a sample. Most people rename it to just wp-config.php and modify it, but if you went through the graphical interface, there is no harm.

As for transferring, since you are making a static-to-live transfer, it is recommended to do this by hand so you will not make any errors with a script.

Although this is a hassle, the next time you need to move it, there are scripts as well as setups for a WordPress-to-WordPress transfer, WordPress-to-Typepad transfer, etc.